# when i try to migrate my profile table its giving me the error .i am using laravel 5.1

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-validation

> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]   syntax
>   error, unexpected '(', expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable
>   (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$'

Here is my code

```
public function up()
        {
            Schema::create('profile', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->('userid')->unsigned()->default(0);
                $table->string('profile')->default('http://localhost/laravel/public/image/uzair.jpg');
                $table->string('about',255);
                $table->foreign('userid')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
                $table->timestamps();
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$table->('userid')
```

This is why you get a syntax error. It should probably be `$table->integer('userid')`.